# Como criar um "glass pane" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, eventos

Estou tentando criar um "*glass pane*" em JavaScript, parecido com [o suportado por Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html). O objetivo é oferecer uma espécie de ajuda interativa ao usuário, onde informações sobre cada elemento são sobrepostas na tela, e todos os elementos exceto aquele que está sendo explicado fica desabilitado.

Criar o glass pane é fácil - basta [um elemento fixo ocupando a tela inteira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079502/520779). Desabilitar todos os elementos exceto um pode ser feito através das propriedades `disabled` e `readonly`, ou [interceptando eventos na fase de captura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21456/215). O problema está em fazer o glass pane **não bloquear** os elementos que estão "atrás" dele.

Para uma demonstração do problema, veja [esse exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/CnVRq/) - todos os elementos funcionam normalmente, até que o link "Ajuda" é clicado; a partir daí, tudo o que está "atrás do glass pane" pára de funcionar, uma vez que os eventos de mouse e teclado vão todos parar no glass pane. Eu gostaria que o glass pane "deixasse passar" os eventos para o que está atrás dele, assim como a versão em Java permite.

Nota: De preferência isso deve ocorrer independentemente do seu grau de trasnparência, ou mesmo de ter ou não coisas desenhadas nele (gostaria de colocar setas e coisas assim).

***Workaround***

Não usar um glass pane, e sim elementos individuais que não bloqueiem o elemento em foco. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/CnVRq/4/). Embora não seja a solução ideal, isso e mais alguma estilização condicional do conteúdo poderia resultar em mais ou menos o que eu quero - só que de forma muito mais trabalhosa...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso pode ser feito via CSS:

```
#glasspane{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Esta propriedade desabilita qualquer evento de mouse no elemento em questão, o que faz com que o elemento logo abaixo de onde você clicou receba os eventos.

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/8s2eh/)

O problema é a compatibilidade com o IE, já que apenas a versão 11+ aceita esta propriedade.

Já o suporte em outros browsers é unânime:

**Chrome** | **FF** | **Safari 7+** | **iOS 3.2+** | **Android 2.1+** <sup>[via CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events)</sup>

Comment: Perfeito! Só tive que adicionar `pointer-events:all` em alguns componentes individuais do glass pane (para que eu pudesse clicar no link "Próximo"), deixando o resto com `none`. [Código final](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/8s2eh/1/). Obrigado pela ajuda!