# Conteúdo html do CKeditor fica vazio após usar o jQuery-ui Sortable na sua div pai

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ckeditor, sortable

Eu quero deixar "sortable" 2 ou mais div's com um CKeditor populado com html, porém ao fazer isso o html do CKeditor perde o conteúdo e o espaço de edição fica bloqueado.

Segue fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/256/

HTML

```
<div id='e'>
    <div id='e1'>
        <textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id='e2'>
        <textarea id="editor2"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS, dentro do ready

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

CKEDITOR.replace('editor2');

$("#e").sortable();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conforme [a resposta do Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39509/215), o problema ocorre ao remover o `iframe` do DOM. Por essa razão, minha sugestão é destruir o editor antes da ordenação (fazendo com que ele volte a ser um simples `textarea`) e recriá-lo após a mesma.

Em primeiro lugar, usa-se a opção [`clone`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-helper) para que o elemento sendo arrastado não seja a própria `div`, mas um clone dela (isso evita que o elemento seja removido do DOM ao iniciar a ordenação, mas sim somente escondido):

```
$("#e").sortable({
    helper:"clone",
```

Dessa forma, o *helper* ainda se parecerá com o editor sendo movido - só que vazio. O elemento original estará ainda no DOM, intacto, mas invisível.

Como o *helper* é uma cópia exata do elemento a ser movido, ele também possui um `iframe`. Pode-se popular esse `iframe` com uma cópia dos dados do próprio editor, para ele se parecer mais com o elemento original. O código abaixo é só um exemplo, provavelmente é possível melhorar mais (a aparência fica bem parecida, salvo por alguns detalhes na fomatação):

```
    start:function(event, ui) {
        // Encontra o id do textarea original (melhor usar classes...)
        while ( event.originalEvent )
            event = event.originalEvent;
        var id = $(event.target).closest("#e1, #e2").find("textarea")[0].id;

        // Acha os dados do editor e os copia pro helper
        var copia = CKEDITOR.instances[id].getData();
        ui.helper.find("iframe").contents().find("body").html(copia);
```

Em seguida, destrói-se o editor no início do processo de ordenar. Como ele está escondido, nenhuma alteração visual é percebida:

```
        CKEDITOR.instances[id].destroy(false);
    },
```

Por fim, ao soltar, recria-se o editor:

```
    stop:function(event) {
        while ( event.originalEvent )
            event = event.originalEvent;
        var id = $(event.target).closest("#e1, #e2").find("textarea")[0].id;

        CKEDITOR.replace(id);
    }
});
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/265/). Um problema desse método é que após se destruir e recriar o editor perde-se todo o histórico de revisões (i.e. *undo* e *redo*), bem como qualquer "estado" que o editor guardasse antes da destruição. Infelizmente não tenho nada a sugerir nesse sentido...

Outro pequeno inconveniente é o *helper*, que idealmente deveria ser uma cópia idêntica do conteúdo sendo movido. Não creio ser simples fazer isso com o editor que usa `iframe` (`iframe`s são um pouco "chatos" de se trabalhar, devido a questões de segurança), mas talvez seja possível aprimorar o método de clonagem.

**Aviso:** Cabe notar que usar o `sortable` dessa forma é sujeito a um problema de UX: se você clicar na área azul/vermelha e arrastar, tudo ok, mas se você clicar por exemplo em um dos botões do editor e acidentalmente mover o mouse, ele inicia uma ordenação (o que pode ser meio irritante pro usuário).

Um meio de evitar isso seria usar um [`handle`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle) para restringir em que parte(s) da `div` se pode arrastar o elemento - em vez da `div` inteira. [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/266/). Ou *talvez* você consiga algo interceptando o clique na [fase de captura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21456/215) e evitando que o *drag* se inicie quando o mesmo ocorrer dentro do `iframe` (não sei como fazer isso usando o `sortable`, não existe nenhum método "beforeStart" ou algo desse tipo...).

Comment: Ficou ótimo no Chrome. Porém no IE ele não encontra toElement/querySelector. O erro é o seguinte: Unable to get property 'querySelector' of undefined or null reference. Com isso no IE(10/9), assim q tento arrastar o CKEditor some.Esse toElement pode ser substituido por outra coisa para não vir null/undefined?

Comment: Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/262/

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Eu inicialmente tentei fazer sem usar jQuery, mas pode-se substituir `x.querySelector(y)` por `$(x).find(y)[0]`. Quanto ao `toElement`, vou investigar, pensei em usar simplesmente `target` mas estranhamente não funcionou (o engraçado é que se você acessar a variável global `event` o `target` está certo, mas no parâmetro `event` que o jQuery usa no *callback* o `target` está diferente...). Quando tiver uma resposta eu atualizo.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Atualizei a resposta pra usar jQuery o tempo todo (em vez de `querySelector`) e consultei o evento original (um `MouseEvent`) em vez do evento jQuery - para garantir que o `target` fosse mesmo o elemento clicado (e não a área inteira). Além é claro de corrigir o bug quando se arrasta o conteúdo do `iframe`. Não tenho como testar no IE(10/9), mas o [último exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/265/) funcionou no IE11, FF, Chrome, Safari e Opera.

Comment: Vou testar hoje e dou um feedback!

Answer (score 12):

## Solução B

<sup>2014-11-11</sup>

Efetivamente, o que acontece é que a `iframe` é automaticamente descarregada quando a estamos a arrastar porque durante o arrastamento ela é desanexada do DOM.

Assim sendo, salvo o previamente sugerido, temos que fazer uso de uma solução que não use `iframe`.

## CKeditor Plugin: [Div Editing Area](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea)

Com o plugin "[Div Editing Area](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea)" conseguimos contornar o problema pois o mesmo não usa uma `iframe` mas sim edição *inline*, o que no permite dispensar da manipulação da `iframe` antes e depois de anexada ao DOM por parte do ato de ser arrastada:

> Este plugin utiliza um elemento `<div>` (em vez do elemento `<iframe>` tradicional) como a área editável no criador themedui. Muito semelhante a edição *inline*, beneficia-se permitindo que o conteúdo do editor herde os estilos de página de acolhimento.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#e").sortable();

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        extraPlugins: 'divarea'
    });

    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
        extraPlugins: 'divarea'
    });
});
```

<sup>Curiosamente, o teu problema está reportado como Bug no CKeditor [Ticket #11857](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11857) que foi entretanto fechado como "inválido" dado o problema estar na forma como a `iframe` é gerida no DOM por parte dos navegadores e não no CKEditor. A recomendação oficial é a forma que já havia sugerido, mas em alternativa este *plugin* sobre o qual agora escrevi também serve como solução.</sup>

---

## Solução A

<sup>2014-11-06</sup>

Dá-me ideia que alguma alteração é feita no DOM no decorrer do arrastamento do elemento e a instância do CKEditor é de alguma forma corrompida.

## Lidar com o problema

Isto não o explica o problema que tens, mas apresenta uma forma de lidar com o mesmo:

[**Ver exemplo no JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/9v0j9e56/)

```js
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
CKEDITOR.replace('editor2');

var $textareaTemplate = $('<textarea/>');

var textareaId = '',
    CKvalue    = '';

$("#e").sortable({
    activate: function( event, ui ) {
        var $textarea = $(ui.item).find('textarea'),
            $userMsg  = $(ui.item).find('.while-drag');

        textareaId = $textarea.attr("id");

        CKvalue = CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].getData();
        CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].destroy();
        $textarea.remove();
        $userMsg.show();
    },
    update: function( event, ui ) {

        $(ui.item).find('.while-drag').hide();
        $(ui.item).append($textareaTemplate.attr("id",textareaId));

        CKEDITOR.replace(textareaId);
        CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].setData(CKvalue);
    }
});
```

## A explicar

- Instanciar o(s) CKEditor como já fazias:

  ```js
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');

  CKEDITOR.replace('editor2');
  ```
- Variáveis globais para guardar dados e o template da área de texto:

  ```js
  // Template da textarea e seus atributos (se aplicavel)
  var $textareaTemplate = $('<textarea/>');


  var textareaId = '', // para guardar a referencia à instancia do CKEditor
      CKvalue    = ''; // para guardar o valor que a instancia do CKEditor contém
  ```
- Instanciar o `sortable` com dois métodos:

  O método [`activate( event, ui )`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-activate) é chamado quando o arrastamento começa em determinado elemento da lista ordenável.

  O método [`update( event, ui )`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-update) é chamado quando a lista é atualizada, algo que acontece após o arrastamento ter terminado e as posições de DOM terem sido alteradas.

  ```js
  $("#e").sortable({
    activate: function( event, ui ) { /* ao iniciar */ },
    update: function( event, ui ) { /* ao terminar */ }
  });
  ```
- Guardar o que precisamos ao iniciar o arrastamento:

  ```js
  activate: function( event, ui ) {

      var $textarea = $(ui.item).find('textarea'),     // localizar a textarea
          $userMsg  = $(ui.item).find('.while-drag');  // localizar mensagem ao utilizador

      // Guardar ID para identificar a instância do CKEditor
      textareaId = $textarea.attr("id"); 

      /* Recolher o valor atualmente presente na instância do CKEditor
       * que corresponde ao ID recolhido em cima.
       */
      CKvalue = CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].getData();

      // Destruir a instancia do CKEditor neste elemento.
      CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].destroy();

      // Remover do DOM a textarea
      $textarea.remove();

      // Apresentar mensagem ao utilizador
      $userMsg.show();
  }
  ```
- Repor o que foi guardado ao terminar o arrastamento:

  ```js
  update: function( event, ui ) {

      // Esconder mensagem
      $(ui.item).find('.while-drag').hide();

      // Colocar template da textarea com o ID recolhido
      $(ui.item).append($textareaTemplate.attr("id",textareaId));

      // Nova instancia do CKEditor para o ID recolhido 
      CKEDITOR.replace(textareaId);

      // Passar valor que o CKEditor tinha de volta para a área de edição
      CKEDITOR.instances[textareaId].setData(CKvalue);
  }
  ```

---

Comment: isso já me dá uma direção muito boa na solução do problema. O seu exemplo ainda tem um bug, quando eu troco de lugar outras vezes o CKeditor acaba se perdendo. Vou tentar investigar isso aqui. Caso você tenha ideia do que pode estar acontecendo por favor atualize aqui!

Comment: Hmmm... Com Firefox a correr em Linux consigo andar com o CKEditor para cima e para baixo múltiplas vezes sem perder o conteúdo... Oportunamente irei analisar melhor este problema e atualizo a resposta!

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Muito provavelmente o problema acontece quando você clica em algo dentro do próprio editor e arrasta. Veja no final da minha resposta para uma explicação e possível solução. A propósito, minha sugestão é bastante parecida com esta, só muda a forma de fazer. E em ambos os casos, ao se mover o elemento perde-se o histórico de edições (*undo* e *redo*). Talvez se perca mais coisas também, não sei... Se a solução B dessa resposta funcionar (i.e. sem precisar destruir e recriar o editor), ela deve ser a melhor opção.